# Convert string to title case

Tags: ruby, rspec

I feel like I'm really close with this one but I can't figure out why `.join` isn't working.

This is the code I wrote:

```
class String
  def title_case
    title = self.split
    title.each do |word|
      unless (word.include?("of")) || (word.include?("the")) && (title.first != "the")
        word.capitalize!
      end
    title.join(" ")
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the RSPEC:

```
describe "String" do
  describe "Title case" do
    it "capitalizes the first letter of each word" do
      "the great gatsby".title_case.should eq("The Great Gatsby")
    end
    it "works for words with mixed cases" do
      "liTTle reD Riding hOOD".title_case.should eq("Little Red Riding Hood")
    end
    it "ignores articles" do
      "The lord of the rings".title_case.should eq("The Lord of the Rings")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you formatted the code properly, you'd see that you misplaced the `#join` call. It needs to be outside of `each` loop.

```
def title_case
  title = self.split
  title.each do |word|
    unless (word.include?("of")) || (word.include?("the")) && (title.first != "the")
      word.capitalize!
    end
  end
  title.join(" ")
end
```

But using `map` and non-destructive `capitalize` (as in @xdazz's answer) would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.map` instead of `.each`:

```
class String
  def title_case
    title = self.split
    title.map do |word|
      unless (word.include?("of")) || (word.include?("the")) && (title.first != "the")
        word.capitalize
      end
    end.join(" ")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of (subtle) re-indentation shows your problem:

```
class String
  def title_case
    title = self.split
    title.each do |word|
      unless (word.include?("of")) || (word.include?("the")) && (title.first != "the")
        word.capitalize!
      end
      title.join(" ")
    end # End of each
  end # End of def
end
```

You are returning the value of the call to `each`. The fix is to move `title.join(" ")` down one line, after the end of `each`, and before the end of the method definition.